# How can I generate a alphanumeric series in Python

Tags: python

I want to generate alphanumeric series for printing the invoice number.

Example: MT00001, MT00002, MT00003

It should not be random.

Please help me.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Django. And please make some effort to solve it yourself and ask when you're really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty straight forward

```
>>> class letter_generator:
...  def __init__(self, prefix, places):
...   self.prefix = prefix
...   self.places = places
...  current = 0
...  def get_unique_id(self):
...   self.current+=1
...   return "%s%s" % (self.prefix, str(self.current).zfill(self.places))
...
>>>
>>> l = letter_generator('TM',5)
>>> l.get_unique_id()
'TM00001'
>>> l.get_unique_id()
'TM00002'
>>> l.get_unique_id()
'TM00003'
>>> l.get_unique_id()
'TM00004'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining list comprehension and string formatting:

```
['MT%05d' % i for i in range(1, 100000)]
```

The result is the list of all invoice numbers in range MT00001...MT99999.